# Is there A Way To Use Google Image Search API From Android?

Tags: android, image

Is there a way to use Google Image Search API from Android application?

Official page (http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/) talks about using the API from a website. I'd like to use it from android application. I'd like to get URL of a first image for the specified keyword which will user enter in my applicaton. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update:

this api is no longer valid and has been replaced with a custom search engine that is probably not what you are looking for

---

I can't see any reason you can't use the normal REST/JSON interface [Google has documented](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/jsondevguide.html) (intended for Flash webapps but seems legal to use for other non-Javascript purposes too).
According to Google:

> The Google Image Search JSON interface, and this guide, are provided for Flash developers, and all other developers who need to access Image Search from other Non-JavaScript environments.

Seems like Android would qualify, assuming you meet all the other TOS requirements like attribution, user-generated queries, and so on.

Comment: You beat me to it, I was in mid-answer when yours came in, mine was almost identical, quoting the docs and all ;) (nice feature of so to let me know, hadn't seen that before).

Comment: ah yeah the old SO "someone beat you to the punch" notice... I know the feeling :)

Comment: As of 2011 the Google Image Search JSON interface is deprecated. The new version is the Custom Search Engine. However, it's not free.