# Search on images.google.com from Android app

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application for the first time.
I am able to do a www.google.com search with this code:

```
    public void onSearchClick(View v) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        String term = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```

But is it also possible to do a search like that on images.google.com (with a word that was filled in the editText-widget)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240586/is-there-a-way-to-use-google-image-search-api-from-android

Comment: I don't want to search by providing a picture. I want to search the normal way by providing a word.

Comment: A simple `intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,       Uri.parse("http://images.google.com"));` would take you to google images where you can search. If thats what you need, I'll make this my answer so that you can accept :)

Comment: I already had this. But can I add a word like I can on the normal google.com search. e.g. I write "car" into the editText and click on the button. It should lead me to images.google.com with the results of cars.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the right way. But it works. Try `intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://images.google.com/search?num=10&hl=en&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=667&q=cars&oq=cars&gs_l=img.3..0l10.748.1058.0.1306.4.4.0.0.0.0.165.209.2j1.3.0...0.0...1ac.1.8RNsNEqlcZc"));` Note that in the url, instead of `q=cars`, give your edittext value.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you for that hint. But maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: just http://images.google.com/search?q=value should work.

Comment: Doesn't work. Redirects to www.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find an elegant way. But you can use this :) `intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://images.google.com/search?num=10&hl=en&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp‌​&biw=1366&bih=667&q=cars&oq=cars&gs_l=img.3..0l10.748.1058.0.1306.4.4.0.0.0.0.165‌​.209.2j1.3.0...0.0...1ac.1.8RNsNEqlcZc"));` where `q='Your_search_text'`

Answer (score 1):

a bit late to the party.

I was trying to do much the same thing, stumbled on this [Android: Google Images Search Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082174/android-google-images-search-results)
,and found that the following query should be more "elegant" - but of course no guarantee that Google would not change it -:

Take "cheetah" as an example for query,

```
https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=cheetah
```

should do the trick.

This should have come close  to  Shashank Kadne's suggestion in the comment above.