# Android: Google Images Search Results

Tags: android, image, search

I am building an android application, and I want to redirect my users to `WebView` with Google Images search results for specific key(and may be some extra search options like screen size).

I searched the web but I did not found any solutions, please help.

*Also, I don't want to use `Bing API`

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about bing api, but if I would do something similar to what you described, then I would use such approach:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=hello+world");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Much easier

You may consider this as an alternative solution for your problem